# Does jQuery make a deep or shallow copy when using append()

Tags: jquery, dom

Example code:

```
jQueryElement.append(jQueryOtherElement.remove("#some-selector"))
```

Will this make a copy of my element and append it or will it actually use the DOM objects?

Basically, I'm wondering if the above code is using innerHTML and if so, is there a way (in jQuery?) to append the DOM nodes after removing them from another location.

Comment: I think matt has the confusion whether .remove gets executed first or append in his case

Comment: @refhat no I'm not confused about that.

Comment: then how can you append something if you have removed it.

Comment: @refhat - `.remove()` removes the DOM elements from the DOM, but keeps them in the jQuery object.  DOM elements can exist outside the DOM as long as some code keeps a reference to them.  That jQuery object is then passed to `.append()` where they are reinserted back into the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will actually use the DOM objects removed by the `.remove()` call - it is not using innerHTML, but rather the actual DOM nodes.  There is no need to copy as the previous DOM objects were removed from the DOM and are available to be inserted.

If you look at the jQuery 1.7 code, the remove function internally calls:

```
elem.parentNode.removeChild( elem )
```

which just removes the node from the DOM.  The nodes are all left in the jQuery object so when you then call append on that jQuery object, they are all still available to be appended directly with any copy or conversion.

Comment: Another question: will these DOM nodes maintain any jQuery.data() applied to them? Forgive my ignorance but I'm just unfamiliar with alot of the inner workings of jQuery.

Comment: @Matt - `.remove()` explicitly removes all jQuery data.  If you want to keep jQuery data, you can use `.detach()`.  References: [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/), [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it'll use the DOM objects. They still exist, just not inside another element. jQuery objects aren't magic :)